# ejabberd - Disable MySQL without recompiling

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have an ejabberd application in production. I've been using MySQL for a couple of month, but now I've decided to migrate to a different db (I've created a custom module which I have in production). The problem is that even when no module is setup with "dbtype: mysql", ejabberd needs the odbc configuration to start, and creates the connection to mysql. I want to disable mysql.

I know I can recompile the code without the --enable-mysql flag, but I'm wondering if there is a way to stop ejabberd for trying to connect to mysql without recompiling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something wrong in your configuration. MySQL can be disabled by not configuring MySQL in the configuration. Maybe you have configured default database backend to be MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed pretty obvious but it didn't work the first time (I'm assuming I forgot something). I've tried again and it worked :)